# Как задать конкретное расстояние между двумя виджетами в QHBoxLayout?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qlayout, spacing

Мой код создает вертикальный контейнер `v_box`, он является главным контейнером окна и содержит в себе горизонтальный контейнер `h_box`, который я покрасил в желтый цвет.

Контейнер `h_box` содержит три виджета:

- Надпись `label_1`,
- Кнопка `btn`,
- Надпись `label_2`.

Надпись `label_1` прижата к левому краю `h_box` и должна оставаться там всегда.

Надпись `label_2` прижата к правому краю `h_box` и должна оставаться там всегда.

Кнопка `btn` сейчас не имеет конкретного местоположения и я хочу это исправить. На картинке ниже показал расстояние между `label_1` и `btn` - **d**.

Мне нужно задать **конкретную и постоянную** величину этого расстояния в пикселях. Пожалуйста, подскажите как мне это сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        v_box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        box = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        box.setStyleSheet(box_qss)
        box.setFixedHeight(50)
        h_box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(box)
        v_box.addWidget(box)

        label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel('label_1')
        h_box.addWidget(label_1)

        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('btn')
        btn.setStyleSheet(btn_qss)
        btn.setFixedSize(40, 30)
        h_box.addWidget(btn, alignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        
        label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel('label_2')
        h_box.addWidget(label_2, alignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)

box_qss = '''QWidget {
                      background-color: yellow;
                      border-radius: 5px;
                  }'''

btn_qss = '''QWidget {
                      background-color: white;
                      border-radius: 5px;
                  }'''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: с возвращением :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> void QBoxLayout::addSpacing(int size)
>
> Добавляет нерастяжимое пространство (QSpacerItem) с размером size в конец этого макета блока. QBoxLayout предоставляет поля и интервалы по умолчанию. Эта функция добавляет дополнительное пространство.

> void QBoxLayout::addStretch(int stretch = 0)
>
> Добавляет растягиваемое пространство (QSpacerItem) с нулевым минимальным размером и коэффициентом растяжения до конца этого макета блока.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        v_box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        box = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        box.setStyleSheet(box_qss)
        box.setFixedHeight(50)
        h_box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(box)
        v_box.addWidget(box)

        label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel('label_1')
        h_box.addWidget(label_1) 
        
        h_box.addSpacing(30)                                       # +++

        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('btn')
        btn.setStyleSheet(btn_qss)
        btn.setFixedSize(40, 30)
        h_box.addWidget(btn)                                       #, alignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        
        h_box.addStretch(1)                                        # +++
        
        label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel('label_2')
        h_box.addWidget(label_2, alignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)

box_qss = '''QWidget {
                      background-color: yellow;
                      border-radius: 5px;
                  }'''

btn_qss = '''QWidget {
                      background-color: white;
                      border-radius: 5px;
                  }'''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Рад видеть ваш ответ снова спустя несколько месяцев. Я очень вам благодарен

Comment: @MAXIM045 новый проект будите делать?

Comment: Продолжение старого проекта равносильно новому. Поэтому я решил доработать плеер, который делал ранее. К сожалению, у меня еще очень много вопросов